# replace the same occurring number with another random number

Tags: python, r, regex, notepad++

In a text file, I have several thousands of the `2000` occurrences. I want to replace all of the occurrences with a random number from 1990 to 2020. How can I do this in regex, or python, notepad++, R ? thanks.

 the occurrences are all like this:

```
"myDate" : "2000_02",
```

### update:

here is the solution suggested by [Kropalis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940627/4835480):

```
import fileinput
from random import randint
textToReplace = randint(1990, 2020)
textToSearch = 2000
fileToSearch = "C:\data.json"
with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
```

but i get a syntax error on :

```
print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
```

Comment: Read the file line by line, replace `2000` with either regex, or some other method with the random module, and write to another file line by line.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace all the occurrences with a random number? Or do you want to replace each occurrence with random numbers?

Comment: What is the format of your file? Is `2000` separated by spaces or a substring of a string?

Comment: @hwnd it put an example in the question, updated it. it is originally in json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really get what you mean, but if you want to replace a **specific** text in your file with a random integer then try:

```
import fileinput
from random import randint
with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
```

with `textToReplace = randint(1990, 2020)`

Hope that helps

Comment: how do you define myfile.txt in the code?

Comment: ` fileToSearch = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\yourfile.txt' ` or wherever your file is located

Comment: Without the ` part. Didn't recognize it as a code, so basically

Comment: fileToSearch = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\yourfile.txt

Comment: syntax error here: print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')

Comment: try .rstrip() instead of end=''

Comment: can you edit your answer with the new modif?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import re
import random

input_file = open('filename.txt', 'r').read()
output_data = re.sub('2000', str(random.randint(1990, 2020)), input_file)
```

Comment: how do i define my entry file to search in?

Comment: Updated answer...

Comment: i get this typerror:
`TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: Convert `randint` to string...